# the select item identified by the order by number_1 contains a variable as a part of the expression identifying a column position

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Alx_GetCurrespondentSubledger] -- '01-Jan-2016',NULL
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime,
    @CorrespondetID bigint = -1,
    @CorrespondentAccountID bigint = -1,
    @TransactionTypeID bigint = -1,
    @TrxnCurrencyID bigint = -1,
    @PageNo int = 0,
    @NumberOfRecords int = 20
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on

    declare
        @StartNo bigint = 0,
        @EndNo bigint = 0,
        @TotalRecords bigint = 0

    SET @StartNo = @PageNo * @NumberOfRecords;

    select     
        L.TrxnDate, L.TrxnCode,
        p.ProductCode, L.TrxnCurrencyQty, L.TrxnCurrencyRate, L.TTExpence, 
        L.LocalCurrncyRecvQty AS Debit,
        L.LocalCurrncyIssQty As Credit
    from 
        [dbo].[ALX_CurrespondentWACostLedger] as L
    left outer join 
        ALX_Products P on L.TrxnCurrencyID = P.ProductID
    where
        L.TrxnDate BETWEEN ISNULL(@FromDate, Convert(date,getDate())) AND ISNULL(@ToDate,GetDate())
AND ((@CorrespondetID>0 AND L.CorrespondentID=@CorrespondetID) OR @CorrespondetID<=0)
AND((@CorrespondentAccountID>0 AND L.CorrespondentAccountID=@CorrespondentAccountID)OR @CorrespondentAccountID<=0)
AND((@TransactionTypeID>0AND L.TransactionTypeID=@TransactionTypeID)OR @TransactionTypeID<=0)
AND((@TrxnCurrencyID>0AND L.TrxnCurrencyID=@TrxnCurrencyID)or @TrxnCurrencyID<=0)
ORDER BY @TransactionTypeID
OFFSET @StartNo ROWS
FETCH NEXT @NumberOfRecords ROWS ONLY
end
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a parameter in the `ORDER BY` clause.

A solution is to use a `CASE` statement instead, evaluating the different possibilities of what your variable can contain and adapting the `ORDER BY` with a real column.

But here, it looks like your parameter `@TransactionTypeID` only refers to the column `L.TransactionTypeID` so hardcoding that should achieve what you want.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Alx_GetCurrespondentSubledger] -- '01-Jan-2016',NULL
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime,
    @CorrespondetID bigint = -1,
    @CorrespondentAccountID bigint = -1,
    @TransactionTypeID bigint = -1,
    @TrxnCurrencyID bigint = -1,
    @PageNo int = 0,
    @NumberOfRecords int = 20
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on

    declare
        @StartNo bigint = 0,
        @EndNo bigint = 0,
        @TotalRecords bigint = 0

    SET @StartNo = @PageNo * @NumberOfRecords;

    select     
        L.TrxnDate, L.TrxnCode,
        p.ProductCode, L.TrxnCurrencyQty, L.TrxnCurrencyRate, L.TTExpence, 
        L.LocalCurrncyRecvQty AS Debit,
        L.LocalCurrncyIssQty As Credit
    from 
        [dbo].[ALX_CurrespondentWACostLedger] as L
    left outer join 
        ALX_Products P on L.TrxnCurrencyID = P.ProductID
    where
        L.TrxnDate BETWEEN ISNULL(@FromDate, Convert(date,getDate())) AND ISNULL(@ToDate,GetDate())
AND ((@CorrespondetID>0 AND L.CorrespondentID=@CorrespondetID) OR @CorrespondetID<=0)
AND((@CorrespondentAccountID>0 AND L.CorrespondentAccountID=@CorrespondentAccountID)OR @CorrespondentAccountID<=0)
AND((@TransactionTypeID>0AND L.TransactionTypeID=@TransactionTypeID)OR @TransactionTypeID<=0)
AND((@TrxnCurrencyID>0AND L.TrxnCurrencyID=@TrxnCurrencyID)or @TrxnCurrencyID<=0)
ORDER BY L.TransactionTypeID
OFFSET @StartNo ROWS
FETCH NEXT @NumberOfRecords ROWS ONLY
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a integer parameter in the ORDER BY clause because the value of the parameter will be treated as a column position. T-SQL doesn't allow this and it throws the error.

If you want to specify an integer *value* to control the sort, an expression containing the parameter is acceptable:

```
ORDER BY @TransactionTypeID + 0
```

If you want to specify a selected value should be sorted to the top of the resultset, you can use a CASE expression that evaluates to a value to control the order:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @TransactionTypeID = L.TransactionTypeID THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Either is enough to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `CASE` at the sort by, something like:

```
ORDER BY CASE @TransactionTypeID

WHEN 'FirstName' THEN {Employee}.[FirstName]

WHEN 'LastName' THEN {Employee}.[LastName]

WHEN 'Email' THEN {Employee}.[Email]

WHEN 'Phone' THEN {Employee}.[Phone]

WHEN 'Salary' THEN {Employee}.[Salary]
```